# How to identify blank profile pictures (nothing uploaded)

Tags: facebook, profile, image

Some users does not have any profile picture uploaded. There is a way to identify users with blank profile pictures?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555199/how-to-determine-if-a-facebook-user-has-uploaded-a-profile-picture-or-its-defaul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you detect that the profile picture returned has a file extension of `gif`, the user does not have a profile picture setup and they are using the default facebook (grey and blue) avatar.
Example : 
`https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v1/yL/r/HsTZSDw4avx.gif`